# Cache asset via freshness in Angular 6 Service Worker

Tags: angular, caching, service-worker, offline-caching

I'm trying to integrate the Angular Service Worker into a existing project. If I understood it correctly there are two cases how data gets cached in Angular SW. It is possible to prefetch or lazyupdate the asset data and to cache specific API calls and other XHR requests.

What I'm trying to achieve is to load an specific asset first via network, if the request runs into a timeout or is not accessible it will be served via the cache. Just like the `freshness` strategy when caching API calls.
But it seems that there's no possible way to configure such a freshness loading mechanism for a JS file which is loaded as an asset in the Angular project.
I've setup an example Project for testing: https://github.com/philipp-schaerer-lambdait/angular-service-worker-test

The following example is a standard Angular App and does not contain the actual project I'm working with but shows the elements I'd like to cache, the structure looks like this:

```
\_ Angular root  
 |_ src/
   |_ index.html <----------- links to excluded_asset.js
   |_ app/
   |_ assets/
     |_ excluded_asset.js <-- this one is excluded in ngsw-config.json
     |_ included_asset.js
     |_ ...
```

Here the relevant configurations:

ngsw-config.json

```
{
    "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "installMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": ["/favicon.ico", "/index.html", "/*.css", "/*.js"]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "assets",
            "installMode": "lazy",
            "updateMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": ["/assets/**", "!/assets/excluded_asset.js"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to achieve a caching behavior like the `freshness` strategy by using the `installMode` and `updateMode` for the assets?

I've tried to exclude it from the asset cache and it was loaded via network but obviously won't be delivered by the service worker after going offline.

After that I've tried to include it again via `dataGroups` and setting the strategy to `freshness` but it seems that the asset won't get cached again once it is excluded from the asset configuration. Also I don't think that the `dataGroups` settings can be used for this file.

```
"dataGroups": [
    {
        "name": "config",
        "urls": ["assets/excluded_asset.js"],
        "cacheConfig": {
            "maxSize": 10,
            "maxAge": "1d",
            "timeout": "100",
            "strategy": "freshness"
        }
    }
}
```

Did I miss something or is there no way to cache an asset via the `freshness` strategy? It would be preferable not to move the file or to change how the file is being requested.

EDIT

I tried to move it outside the cached assets directories and include it with the `dataGroups` setting, didn't work either.

Answer (score 9):

**New app with the service worker**

The command will be following:

```
ng new myApp --service-worker (or using the alias — -sw )
```

Having this service worker flag, Angular CLI 1.6 will do some automation for us:

1. Angular Service Worker package will be installed.
2. Build support for NGSW will be enabled.
3. NGSW will be registered for your application.
4. NGSW configuration file will be created with some smart defaults.

Anyway, even after CLI 1.6 will be released, it’s good to know how to reproduce these steps, because we have to perform them manually to add NGSW support to the existing app. Let’s go to add Angular Service Worker to PWAtter.

**Adding Angular Service Worker to the existing app**

Let’s manually perform the same 4 steps from above:

**1. Install NGSW**

```
npm install @angular/service-worker --save
```

**2. Enable build support (only for Angular CLI 1.6, see the notice below)**

```
ng set apps.0.serviceWorker=true
```

or manually add/edit this parameter in `.angular-cli.json` file.

> Important! For the moment, when we use Angular CLI 1.5, please make
>   sure that you don’t have this property in `.angular-cli.json`, it will
>   cause build errors. See how to emulate this step in Angular CLI 1.5
>   below.

**3. Register NGSW** in your `AppModule`. This is how it will look in Angular
    CLI 1.6:

```
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker'
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    environment.production ? ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js') : []
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**4. Create NGSW** configuration file (default name is src/ngsw-config.json). Here is the default content will be generated by Angular CLI 1.6.

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html"
      ],
      "versionedFiles": [
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

At the moment, while using Angular CLI 1.5 we also have to emulate build support from the step 2. Actually, there are 2 extra actions should perform in addition to `ng build --prod` command (it’s important to use production build in order to use NGSW!):

**Generate NGSW** control (manifest) file ngsw.json based on NGSW configuration file src/ngsw-config.json using NGSW CLI ngsw-config.

**Copy NGSW** itself from the npm_modules package folder to our dist folder.

To have one simple command to generate production build with NGSW support let’s add some npm scripts:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "ngsw-config": "node_modules/.bin/ngsw-config dist src/ngsw-config.json",
    "ngsw-copy": "cp node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js dist/",
    "build-prod-ngsw": "ng build --prod && npm run ngsw-config && npm run ngsw-copy",
    "serve-prod-ngsw": "npm run build-prod-ngsw && http-server dist -p 8080"
  }
}
```

Now if we run `npm run build-prod-ngsw` we’ll have Angular PWA in the `dist` folder. Optionally, we could serve it using the simplest `http-server` by running `npm run serve-prod-ngsw`.

> Important! Do not use `ng serve` to test your Angular Service Worker.
>   This development server was not designed to work in collaboration with
>   PWA flow. Always build a production version of the app and serve it
>   from your distributive folder using any static web server.

**Application shell**

If we perform the above actions and run `npm run build-prod-ngsw` — the Angular PWA in its default form is ready for us! Deploy the application or just run it locally using any static web server (`http-server` package in my case, you run `npm run serve-prod-ngsw` to build and serve).

The application will be working after we went offline. Why? Because NGSW cached all the resources listed in theassetGroups section of the configuration file, and now it’s responsible for serving them from the Cache Storage, which is full of records now:

[image]

Service Worker is registered and active

[image]

We can view the content of cached response (available only in Chrome Canary at the moment)

NGSW uses Cache Storage to store both HTTP responses data and some metadata to handle versioning:

[image]

Types of the storages by NGSW

- Entries with postfix `:cache` — actual HTTP responses.
- Entries with postfix `:meta` — to store the versioning meta information. Later this kind of stored data might be moved to `indexedDB`.

> If you keep DevTools open, the entries inside Cache Storage section
>   most likely will not be updated automatically after each action from
>   service worker side. If you wish to see the actual data, right-click
>   and choose Refresh Caches.

Right. The default form of NGSW configuration file is not enough for our case because we use Material Icons webfont. Obviously, these resources (corresponding CSS and WOFF2 files) were not cached by NGSW, but we can easily fix it by adding one more group to `assetGroups` in addition to default `app` and `assets` ones. Let’s call it `fonts`:

```
{
  ...
  "assetGroups": [
   ...
   {
    "name": "fonts",
    "resources": {
      "urls": [
        "https://fonts.googleapis.com/**",
        "https://fonts.gstatic.com/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

It makes sense to specify these resources using globs syntax because the exact URL of the font file could change from time to time to support webfont versioning. Also, you may notice that we have specified neither `installMode` nor `updateMode`. On the one hand, both will be set as `prefetch` in the resulting NGSW control file as this is a default value. On the other hand, they will be cached only after they were requested because the specifics of `urls`-way to list the resources.

After we rebuild, run and switch to offline mode we will see the normal state of the application with all the icons in the place.

In the Cache Storage we’ll see two new entries:

[image]

Storages generated by NGSW

We can even preview the cached font:

[image]

There is a fundamental difference between `assetGroups` and `dataGroups`.

- `assetGroups` are keeping track of the app [shell] version.
- `dataGroups` are independent of the app version. They are cached using
  their own cache policies, and it’s the proper section to handle our
  API responses.

**Runtime caching**

To use Network-First strategy for my `/timeline` API endpoint and Cache-First strategy for the `/favorites` endpoint. The corresponding setup in `src/ngsw-config.json` will look like:

```
{
  ...
  "dataGroups": [{
      "name": "api-freshness",
      "urls": [
        "/timeline"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "freshness",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d",
        "timeout": "10s"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "/favorites"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There is a main switch defining the behavior of NGSW: `cacheConfig / strategy`. For network-first strategy, it’s `freshness`, for cache-first — `performance`.

Now build, serve, click Load my timeline and Load my favorites buttons to get and cache API responses, and switch to offline.

About the optimization for online mode. Return back to online and click `Timeline / Favorites` once or twice. It’s clearly visible that Favorites are loaded immediately, just because we skip the whole network trip and get the data from the cache. To specify for how long to cache Using settings in `cacheConfig` section — we have the fine-grain control there.

NGSW helped us a lot with some really smart network optimizations, requiring only some JSON configuration from us.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed step by step installation instructions for the Angular Service Worker. It does not directly answer my question on how to fetch an asset by network first if possible and by cache if a timeout or network error is returned. I'll try some maxAge and maxSize config settings and give feedback again.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem. The solution I've found to always having up-to-date js and css files is simply to exclude the index.html from the cached assets.

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js",
          "!/index.html" // Right here!!!!!
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "lazy",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/static/**"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Be sure to have `"outputHashing": "all",` to your angular build configuration. That way when you make a change to your code, it will generate a file with a different name. It will then automatically add the script tag (or link tag) to your html file (which the service worker will ignore) and as soon as you push your changes to production, the index.html will point to your new js and css files.

Of course this sucks in a very obvious way: your index.html won't be cached by the service worker, but at least it will allow returning users to have the freshest files straight up.

I really wished there was a way to have a "freshness" option for assets too...