# Angular 7 Service Worker not caching assets in production

Tags: angular, service-worker

In a local environment my Ng7 app works perfectly when serviced by `http-server`. However, when deployed online with Netlify no files are cached using the following `ngsw-config.json`

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have found that is caches **some** of the `js` files but they all have a 0 content length, meaning they actually don't even have any content. Interestingly, it refuses to cache the main.HASH.js file which is actually the largest.

[image: Cached file list]

**UPDATE**

I have taken my lead from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850760/cache-asset-via-freshness-in-angular-6-service-worker) and removed `index.html` from the files I can get the `.js` file list to show in the cache store.

[image: cached file list]
However as before, they all have a content length of zero!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to set the installMode of the assets to "prefetch" - this ensures that the given ressources will be cached by ServiceWorker when your app starts. You set it to lazy - which means that only ressources will be cached when they are requested. See [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config)
Sometimes (my experiences with it) updateMode causes problems - so give it a first try without the assets "updateMode". So the ngsw-config.json will look like this:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```